# Facebook SDK returned an error: Access token was not returned from Graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication

What does mean the error:
*Facebook SDK returned an error: Access token was not returned from Graph.*
?

Older code have stopped suddenly and I have to implement a new Facebook Authentication script.

What I do wrong? What I need also?

My code:

```
if(!session_id()) {

    session_start();

}



include_once APP_PATH . "plugins/fbsdk-v5/autoload.php";



use Facebook\Facebook;

use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException;

use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException;



$fb = new Facebook([

    'app_id' => $_SESSION['config']['social_facebook_id'],

    'app_secret' => $_SESSION['config']['social_facebook_auth'],

    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',

]);



$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();



$permissions = array('email','public_profile');



try {

    if(isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {

        $accessToken = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];

    }

    else {

        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();

    }

} catch(FacebookResponseException $e) {

     echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();

} catch(FacebookSDKException $e) {

    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();

}



if(isset($accessToken)){

    if(isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {

        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);

    }

    else {



        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = strval($accessToken);



        $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();



        $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);

        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = strval($longLivedAccessToken);





        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);

    }



    if(isset($_GET['code'])){

        header('Location: ./');

    }





    try {

        $profileRequest = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name,email', $accessToken);

        $fbUserProfile = $profileRequest->getGraphNode()->asArray();

    } catch(FacebookResponseException $e) {

        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();

        session_destroy();



        header("Location: ./");

        exit;

    } catch(FacebookSDKException $e) {

        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();

        exit;

    }




    $fbUserData = array(

        'oauth_provider'=> 'facebook',

        'oauth_uid'     => $fbUserProfile['id'],

        'first_name'    => $fbUserProfile['first_name'],

        'last_name'     => $fbUserProfile['last_name'],

        'email'         => $fbUserProfile['email'],

        'gender'        => $fbUserProfile['gender'],

        'locale'        => $fbUserProfile['locale'],

        'picture'       => $fbUserProfile['picture']['url'],

        'link'          => $fbUserProfile['link']

    );



    $_SESSION['userData'] = $userData;



    $logoutUrl = $helper->getLogoutUrl($accessToken, APP_URL . "users/logout.html");



}

else {

    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(APP_URL . "users/login-using-facebook.html", $permissions);

}
```

---

My new code:

```
<?php



include_once APP_PATH . "plugins/fbsdk-v5/autoload.php";



use Facebook\Facebook;

use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException;

use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException;

$fb = new Facebook(array(

  'app_id' => $_SESSION['config']['social_facebook_id'],

  'app_secret' => $_SESSION['config']['social_facebook_auth'],

  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.3',

));

if($_GET['action'] == 'login-using-facebook') { // callback

    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

    try {
      $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
      var_dump($accessToken);
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      // When Graph returns an error
      echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      //exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      // When validation fails or other local issues
      echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      //exit;
    }

    if (! isset($accessToken)) {
      if ($helper->getError()) {
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        echo "Error: " . $helper->getError() . "\n";
        echo "Error Code: " . $helper->getErrorCode() . "\n";
        echo "Error Reason: " . $helper->getErrorReason() . "\n";
        echo "Error Description: " . $helper->getErrorDescription() . "\n";
      } else {
        header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
        echo 'Bad request';
      }
      exit;
    }

    // Logged in
    var_dump($accessToken->getValue());

    // The OAuth 2.0 client handler helps us manage access tokens
    $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

    // Get the access token metadata from /debug_token
    $tokenMetadata = $oAuth2Client->debugToken($accessToken);
    var_dump($tokenMetadata);

    // Validation (these will throw FacebookSDKException's when they fail)
    $tokenMetadata->validateAppId($_SESSION['config']['social_facebook_id']); // Replace {app-id} with your app id
    // If you know the user ID this access token belongs to, you can validate it here
    //$tokenMetadata->validateUserId('123');
    $tokenMetadata->validateExpiration();

    if (! $accessToken->isLongLived()) {
      // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
      try {
        $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
      } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        echo "<p>Error getting long-lived access token: " . $helper->getMessage() . "</p>\n\n";
        exit;
      }

      var_dump($accessToken->getValue());
    }

    $_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = strval($accessToken);

}

elseif($_SESSION['fb_access_token']) { // retrieve

    try {
      // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
      $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name', $_SESSION['fb_access_token']);
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }

    $user = $response->getGraphUser();

    echo 'Name: ' . $user['name'];

}

else { // login

    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

    $permissions = array('email');
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(APP_URL."users/login-using-facebook.html", $permissions);


}

?>
```

I used developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_logi‌​n and developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/profilewithgraphapi and it still doesn't work :( I can't understand why the example code is wrong in my script.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: API v2.2 was shut down end of March; you need to use at least v2.3

Comment: @CBroe thank you for your reply but it's the same with v2.3

Comment: Did you have this working before using that script, or did you just write it after old code stopped working? If this is a new script, then I would suggest you go check the examples under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted

Comment: I still can't do it works...
My new code, I have rewritten all using https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/profilewithgraphapi